# Why won't IAM "AmazonEC2FullAccess" policy allow user to launch instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The policies attached to the IAM `developers` group I've set up are as follows:

[image]

However, launching new instances won't work. Just after a user in this group selects the key pair to associate with it, i.e. reaches the final step, they get the following message on the next page:

> **Launch Failed**
>
> You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: WZzytnkJ4T3-nkMYslM...

What's preventing *developers* to launch new instances, given these policies?

Comment: You can decode the message using `aws sts decode-authorization-message` which will give you the reason for this. Full documentation can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html. There could be an overriding policy in the IAM user which could enforce certain tags.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004, where do I need to input that command, exactly?

Comment: see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html for a nice intro to AWS CLI

Comment: I know this might be a daft question but want to rule it out is your user definitely a member of that group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be that the instance is being launched with an **IAM Role**, and the group does not have `iam:PassRole` permissions (which are outside of the `ec2:*` permissions space).

You should add a policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PassRoleToEC2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This saying *"Allow this user to pass any (*) role to an EC2 instance"*.

Actually, you should limit such permissions only to specific roles, otherwise a normal user could select an Admin role. Then, if they logged into the instance, they would have access to credentials that have Admin permissions on the whole AWS Account.

Alternatively, *do not* select a Role when launching the instance. It should then launch okay (assuming that this is the issue causing the error).

Comment: how do I achieve this? And can I achieve it from the AWS console?

Comment: if what he says is the reason to check this you can simply attach the policy that he mentioned in answer to that user and ask them to try again.

Comment: I've added a policy above. Please try to understand what this policy is doing because it could be a vector for breach of security if incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 0):

The user needs a `PassRole` permission.

A Role must be associated with the "Launch" of the EC2 instance.

The PassRole permission helps you make sure that a user doesn’t pass a role to an EC2 instance where the role has more permissions than you want the user to have.

As in the following example, if the EC2 Launch requires access to S3 you User must be able to pass the S3 role required.

```
{
  "Effect":"Allow",
  "Action":"iam:PassRole",
  "Resource":"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/S3Access"
}
```

Link to documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/granting-permission-to-launch-ec2-instances-with-iam-roles-passrole-permission/